# How to call dataflow task from script task in ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, msbi

I have two kind of files (EXCEL and TXT ) if file extension is EXCEL i have to call  data flow task for EXCEL and if it is TXT i have to call data flow task for TXT

How would i call dataflow task from ssis Script task

Answer (score 3):

Create a variable with package as scope having type string. 
Inside Script Task , populate that variable with value .

```
//get file type and store in variable filetype 

if(filetype == "Excel")
  Dts.Variables["User::FileType"].Value = "Excel";

else if(filetype == "Txt")
  Dts.Variables["User::FileType"].Value = "Txt";
```

After that use expression constraint based on that variable value to call the appropriate dataflow task.

For Excel DataFlow Task , precedence constarint will have following expression

```
@[User::FileType] == "Excel"
```

For Text DataFlow Task , precedence constarint will have following expression

```
@[User::FileType] == "Txt"
```

[**Expression and Precedence constraints**](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/working-with-precedence-constraints-in-sql-server-integration-services/) are used to control flow of package execution.

Comment: Hi Sir thanks for writing,i used same condition but both expression evaluated to false and no call to any dataflow task. what should i do to make both condtion to true